# Hash table implementation in C - only junk values inside

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a Chained hash tables in C. It is a project from a course so it doesn't have to be perfect, but I can't get it to work.

In the method that I add new values to the hash table everything seems OK, but later when I try to find some value in the hash table it seems there is nothing inside (or some junk values). I think the hash function is working properly so I would not post it. Here is the relevant code:

```
// typedef a node for the linked list
typedef struct node
{
    char* value;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

// global variables
node* head = NULL;
node* lists[145000];

// this method inserts a new value into the hash table
bool insert_word(char* value, int index)
{
    // inserting at the beginning of the list
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->value = value;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }

    lists[index] = head;

    return true;
}

// this method should check if the searched word
// is present in the hash table
bool check(const char* word)
{
    int index = hash(word);

    node* curr_node = lists[index];

    while (curr_node != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(curr_node->value, word) == 0) // this never happens
        {
            return true;
        }
        curr_node = curr_node->next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I would appreciate any help as I've been struggling with this for two days... Thanks :)

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and you should **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). You really cannot avoid using the debugger

Comment: You don't define `node`  in your code chunk above.

Comment: How is `bool insert_word(char* value, int index) {}` called ? (it might be necessary to strdup() the argument before assigning to node->value )

Comment: Why do you have global `head`? It makes no sense. Your insert function should search correct index first, and then insert the node on linked list there.

Comment: Also, the `node* lists[145000];` array is not initialised. (and to avoid negative indices, you should use unsigned types for hashing and indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating a new node in

```
node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
new_node->value = value;
```

But you are not testing failure of `malloc` and you are not always setting the `next` field of the `new_node` (so that field may contain garbage when `head` is `NULL`).

Try something like

```
node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (!new_node) {perror("malloc node"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
new_node->value = value;  // probably needs:: strdup (value)
new_node->next = NULL;
```

Most importantly, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Use also a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...

At last, we don't know how is  `insert_node` called? I guess (like [joop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235885/joop) commented) that you may want to duplicate the string, e.g. use `new_node->value = strdup(value);`

Comment: Thank you all. Using new_node->value = strdup(value) solved the problem.